# Sending confirmation email when user registered by codeigniter in localhost

Tags: php

I wrote a code that register user and send the confirmation email to user after registering. but the code does not send email. only insert data to database.

Comment: This isn't Twitter - you can include detail (the code would be very useful) in your question. Have a look at how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Hold on just for a minute. How are we supposed to help you?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

PHPMailer is the class you should be using to send authentication to users. SSL and TLS are supported. You will have to make minor changes in the config file.
 Hope that solves your problem.

To send mail change the sender email mentioned in the code.